# SQL change decimal(9,3) to decimal(9,2)

Tags: php, sql, casting

In my table: "epf_application_price" column: "retail_price" all values are entered as **decimal(9,3)**. I dont want to change the table format but I want to output this value as **decimal(9,2)** with the following SQL.

```sql
SELECT epf_application_price.retail_price
FROM   epf_application_price
       INNER JOIN app_uri
               ON epf_application_price.application_id = app_uri.application_id
WHERE  app_uri.uri = '$URL'
       AND epf_application_price.storefront_id = '$storefront'
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the extra decimal? Round or truncate?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I want to truncate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo number_format($row['retail_price'],2,'.','');
```

Answer (score 1):

In `SqlServer`

```
Convert(decimal(9,2),retail_price)
```

> It will truncate the last Digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format in mysql

```
FORMAT(epf_application_price,2)
```

you can also use the TRUNCATE

```
TRUNCATE(epf_application_price,2)
```

Some common example of truncate.

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(1.223,1);
        1.2
SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,1);
       1.9
SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999,0);
         1
SELECT TRUNCATE(-1.999,1);
       -1.9
SELECT TRUNCATE(122,-2);
       100
SELECT TRUNCATE(10.28*100,0);
       1028
```

Answer (score 0):

do some thing like this :-

```
SELECT  FORMAT(`prodprice`,2) as productprice from ecart_main_product_size
```

here prodprice is name of column and productprice is alias of formatted column and ecart_main_product_size is the name of table.